# Is 500 the maximum number of iterations in the optimization experiment in the evaluation only version of AnyLogic?

Tags: optimization, anylogic

I tried setting the iteration number to more than 500, but it stopped at 500.
Setting the number to less than 500 would work.

Answer (score 1):

500 is the limitation for the free edition of anyLogic (PLE)
If you want more iterations, you will have to get the student or professional edition.

Comment: Thanks a lot! And may I ask if the optimisation engine selection (genetic and OptQuest) is also only available in research or professional version?